# Execute JavaScript in current Chrome tab in Android (without PC)

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I'd like to execute a simple javascript statement in the context of current Chrome tab, say `console.log("hello")`, preferable via a shell script on the device itself. These are what I have found so far:

- `am start -n com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.Chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity -d 'XXX'` works with address but not JavaScript.
- same for `com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main`
- The legacy workflow shows that there is a UNIX socket for the debugger: `adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote` but I cannot find it anywhere on the device's filesystem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the security model of Chrome, there doesn't seem to have a direct way to do this.

A solution that works for me is a proxy so-called [mitmproxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy) with a custom rule to add the script tag at the end of the `head` tag. `mitmproxy` works with `HTTPS`, too.

```
# Usage: mitmdump -s "modify_response_body.py mitmproxy bananas"
# (this script works best with --anticache)
from libmproxy.models import decoded

def response(context, flow):
    with decoded(flow.response):  # automatically decode gzipped responses.
        flow.response.content = flow.response.content.replace(
            '</head>',
            '<script type="text/javascript">console.log("hello");</script></head>')
```